# How to also save the Generated unique ID in Firebase Realtime Databse

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]Hello Everyone,

I am looking forward to save the unique id generated when saving the information using push method in Firebase Realtime database.

Below is my code

```
String bookid = dbreference.child("books").child(condition).push().getKey();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your question will be uploaded shortly !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                b = new Books(btitle, bauthor, bdesc, condition, sellername, selleremail, sellermobile,  selleruniversity, bprice,bookid);


                dbreference.child("books").child(condition).child(bookid).setValue(b);
```

It stores all the information from textview but in bookid it appears empty which I want to store push key which is "-LVx3qNb1HCxYKRE5cFl"

My Books class is

```
public class Books {
public String bname;
public String bauthor;
public String bdesc;
public String sellername;
public String selleremail;
public String sellermobile;
public String category;
public String selleruniversity;
public String bcondition;
public double price;
public String pics;
 public String bookid;
//  public Uri uri;

public Books(String bname, String bauthor, String bdesc, String bcondition, String sellername, String selleremail, String sellermobile,  String selleruniversity, double price, String bookid) {
    this.bname = bname;
    this.bauthor = bauthor;
    this.bdesc = bdesc;
    this.sellername = sellername;
    this.selleremail = selleremail;
    this.sellermobile = sellermobile;
    this.category = category;
    this.selleruniversity = selleruniversity;
    this.bcondition = bcondition;
    this.price = price;
    this.pics="";
     this.bookid="";
    //   this.uri = uri;
}

public Books(){}
public String getBname() {
    return bname;
}
public String getBauthor() {
    return bauthor;
}
public String getBdesc() {
    return bdesc;
}
public String getSellername() {
    return sellername;
}
public String getSelleremail() {
    return selleremail;
}
public String getSellermobile() { return sellermobile;}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public String getSelleruniversity() {
    return selleruniversity;
}
public String getCondition() { return bcondition;}
public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public String getBookid() {
    return bookid;
}
public String getPics() {
    return pics;
}
public void setPics(String pics) {
    this.pics = pics;
}

}
```

Comment: That's the correct approach to store that generated id in a field but code looks good to. Can you please add the content of your `Books` class, to see it more clearly.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check I have added Books class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `""` in your database because this is how you have instantieted the `bookid` field in your constructor. To solve this, please change in your `Books` class, the following line of code:

```
this.bookid="";
```

to

```
this.bookid = bookid;
```

Comment: Thanks I also noticed when you asked me to paste it...!!

Comment: could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156701/how-to-show-updated-recycleview-adapter-on-click-inside-bindview-holder

Answer (score 1):

Your books class should look like this. You missed adding the parameter's value to your bookid String.

```
public class Books {

public String bname;
public String bauthor;
public String bdesc;
public String sellername;
public String selleremail;
public String sellermobile;
public String category;
public String selleruniversity;
public String bcondition;
public double price;
public String pics;
public String bookid;
//public Uri uri;

public Books(String bname, String bauthor, String bdesc, String bcondition, String sellername, String selleremail, String sellermobile,  String selleruniversity, double price, String bookid) {
this.bname = bname;
this.bauthor = bauthor;
this.bdesc = bdesc;
this.sellername = sellername;
this.selleremail = selleremail;
this.sellermobile = sellermobile;
this.category = category;
this.selleruniversity = selleruniversity;
this.bcondition = bcondition;
this.price = price;
this.pics = "";
this.bookid = bookid;
//this.uri = uri;
}

public Books(){}

public String getBname() {
    return bname;
}
public String getBauthor() {
    return bauthor;
}
public String getBdesc() {
    return bdesc;
}
public String getSellername() {
    return sellername;
}
public String getSelleremail() {
    return selleremail;
}
public String getSellermobile() { return sellermobile;}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public String getSelleruniversity() {
    return selleruniversity;
}
public String getCondition() { return bcondition;}
public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public String getBookid() {
    return bookid;
}
public String getPics() {
    return pics;
}
public void setPics(String pics) {
    this.pics = pics;
}

}
```

Comment: I have added my books class..Please check