# How to show updated RecycleView adapter on click inside Bindview holder?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Recycleview Adapter to show my list of items from Firebase Real-time Database.
I have a button which shows text value from Firebase initially when clicked will change the same key value in Firebase Database and I want it to show the updated text in Button too.

But it doesn't unless exit activity and reopen activity. Then it displays the updated value in Button text instead of the initial one.

How to update and show the value without exiting the Adapter?

I used `notifyItemChanged(position)` but it doesn't do anything.

Here is my Code

```
public class SubjectBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectBooksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Books> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    Books g;
    SubjectBooksAdapter adapter;



    public SubjectBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button mSolved;
        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dbreference = database.getReference("books");
            dbreference.keepSynced(true);
            mSolved = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_solved);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("books");

        g = bookslist.get(position);


        holder.mSolved.setText(g.getMarkid());
        holder.bookName.setText(g.getBname());
        holder.bookprice.setText("Rs. "+g.getPrice());
        holder.sellername.setText(g.getSellername());



        holder.mSolved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference classicalMechanicsRef = rootRef.child("books").child(g.getCondition()).child(g.getBookid());
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSnapshot.child("bmark").getRef().setValue("Solved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
classicalMechanicsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);


notifyItemChanged(position);
            }

        });



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

xml code is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_card_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp" >
          
          <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:padding="2dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="7dp"
                    android:gravity="left">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/book_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".4"
                        android:text="Book Name"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
                 
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seller_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:text="Seller"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <Button
                       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:textColor="#ffffff"
                       android:text="Remove"
                       android:textStyle="bold"
                       android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                       android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:id="@+id/book_solved"
                       android:textAllCaps="false"
                       android:layout_height="35dp"
                       android:background="@drawable/buttonshape1"
                       android:padding="8dp"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/seller_name"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="View Details"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the value you want to change in your adapter you can do using `notifyItemChanged(position)`. `NotifyItemChange` only works when there is a change in your Model Class.

Let say here you are setting the value your Book Name on a `TextView` by using this code.

```
Books g = bookslist.get(position);    
holder.bookName.setText(g.getBname());
```

Now if you want to change the value of Book name on `Button` click you have to change the value in your `ArrayList` Model also then notify it.

```
Books g = bookslist.get(position);    
g.setBname("your new value");
```

After this, your `notifyItemChanged(position)` will display the new value. This is how `notify` works in `RecyclerView`

**Why you have to do so?**

Whenever the notify is called in `RecylerView` it again set the value from the `ArrayList`. But in your case, the value is not updated locally in your list but is updated in the `FireBase`. That's why you get the updated value whenever you again open your app.

**NOTE**

To change the value of `Button` with text Remove, get the `Markid` in the Datachange of the `FireBase`. Then set that value in the respective model(of that position) from the `ArrayList` for `String` `Markid`.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    dataSnapshot.child("bmark").getRef().setValue("Solved");
    // Here you need to save the value in the arraylist.   
    bookslist.get(position).setMardid("Here what ever the value you will pass will get updated on the button after notify"); //Try adding the static string that you want after button click.
    notifyItemChanged(position)
}
```

Comment: so any solution I can replace it with notifyItemChanged(position);??

Comment: I didn't get your question.

Comment: Since notifyItemChanged(position); donot show the updated text value of button unless I finish activity by back pressed and reopen it..So, is there any way to show the updated value as soon button is pressed.

Comment: What is the value of the button initially?

Comment: I have open a new thread with more clarification could you please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/95147131?noredirect=1

Comment: please check Button with text value remove is I'm using to remove the key.

Comment: I have added a note. Try implementing that. Let me know if it is working you.

Comment: It is okay I did the other way ...I'm too tired now to modify that code...I'll vote your answer as yes and in future I'll use it..One last question I used setReverseLayout to sort my list by date ..but now when I open activity then it scrolls to bottom automaticaly which I have to manually go to top..is there any way to force Recycleview to stay at top?

Comment: To Scroll to the top you can use smoothScroll or you can try `setStackFromEnd` as false.  Also to sort the list of `RecyclerView` using `Collections.sort` in your adapter as per your requirements.

Comment: I already use you suggested method but none of it worked..here I opened a thread on same could you please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159877/scroll-recycleview-to-top-position-when-activity-starts-using-linearlayoutmanage